# What is a good  file extention for CLI PHP programs?

Tags: windows, php, file-extension

I use **PHP** for some **OS** scripting, is there any proper file extension other than *.php* for PHP cli programs? So I can assign `php.exe` to run these kind of files directly. Is `.phps` a good candidate?

**I want just CLI programs be opened (by double clicking) by PHP.exe not other php files, so a differnt file extension should be used**

Comment: php.exe? Windows? Please tag your question.

Comment: `phps` indicates to the web server to not execute it, but rather have the contents displayed with syntax highlighting -- the "s" stands for "source".

Comment: @lzzy Thanks, What is your suggestion?

Comment: `.php` is the most commonly used extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create and assign any extension you wish. Simply create a file, give it the extension you desire (that is not already in use), and then right-click it and select *Open With*. Now select the PHP executable from the *Open With* dialog (*Browse* for it if necessary) and select the *Always use…* checkbox.

For the record, `.phps` PHP source-code files that are meant to be rendered as source with syntax-highlighting instead of executed, so you may want to use something else like `.phpcli`

[image]